# AS2 flash menu, that doesn't let inner buttons work properly

Tags: flash, menu, toggle, actionscript-2

I'm using a flash menu builded with AS2. It does what it's supposed to: if you click a button in the menu, this button goes in a selected status, most important, this button fades out only when another button is released. you can see the demo here:

http://activeden.net/item/buttons-section-selected/6100

It works with this code:**

```
//SET STAGE
Stage.scaleMode = "noScale"

//SET BUTTONS TEXT (Here you can change the buttons name)
b1.MC_btnTxt.TXT.text = "Button 1";
b2.MC_btnTxt.TXT.text = "Button 2";
b3.MC_btnTxt.TXT.text = "Button 3";
b4.MC_btnTxt.TXT.text = "Button 4";
b5.MC_btnTxt.TXT.text = "Button 5";

/*CREATE THE BUTTONS ARRAY(if you wanna add or delete 
buttons you have to ad or delete the istance button name from the list*/
var myArray = [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5]; 

//CREATE FUNCTIONS FOR THE BUTTONS ANIMATION
function overBtn (){ 
    for (j=0; j<myArray.length; j++) { 
       myArray[j].onRollOver = function(){ 
       this.gotoAndPlay(2); 
      } 
        myArray[j].onRollOut = function(){ 
        this.gotoAndPlay("fadeOut"); 
      } 
    } 
} 

function releaseStatus() { 
    for (a=0; a<myArray.length; a++) { 
       myArray[a].enabled = false; 
    } 
    deselection(); 
} 

function deselection() { 
    for (b=0; b<myArray.length; b++) { 

        if (b<>selectedBtn) {  
       myArray[b].enabled = true; 
       if(myArray[b]._currentframe==32) 
            myArray[b].gotoAndPlay("selectionFadeOut"); 
        } 
    } 
} 


// SET BUTTONS
b1.onRelease = function() { 
    sectionTXT.text = "Section 1"
    selectedBtn = 0; 
    releaseStatus(); 
    this.gotoAndPlay("selectionFadeIn"); 
} 

b2.onRelease = function() { 
    sectionTXT.text = "Section 2"
    selectedBtn = 1; 
    releaseStatus(); 
    this.gotoAndPlay("selectionFadeIn");  
} 


b3.onRelease = function() { 
    sectionTXT.text = "Section 3"
    selectedBtn = 2; 
    releaseStatus(); 
    this.gotoAndPlay("selectionFadeIn");  
} 

b4.onRelease = function() { 
    sectionTXT.text = "Section 4"
    selectedBtn = 3; 
    releaseStatus(); 
    this.gotoAndPlay("selectionFadeIn"); 
} 

b5.onRelease = function() { 
    sectionTXT.text = "Section 5"
    selectedBtn = 4; 
    releaseStatus(); 
    this.gotoAndPlay("selectionFadeIn");  
}

//INIT INTERFACE
overBtn();
```

The problem is that, if you want to add a button inside the buttons (b1, b2, b3...) the inner buttons doesn´t work. For instance: the code below doesn´t works for a button inside one of the main buttons (b5).

```
b5.ex .onRelease = function ()
{
    this.gotoAndStop("selectionInnerButton"); 
}
;
```

My question is: What should I change in the code in order to make the inner buttons work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:  Go into your button.

Step 2: Right-click the sub-button

Step 3: make an onclick function for it (`this.onRelease = function()`)

Step 4:  In the construction code, access the `parent` of the sub-button, and tell it to go to the `selectionInnerButton` frame like you've been doing:  `_parent.gotoAndStop('selectionInnerButton')`

And there you go.  However, what's wrong with your current code is that I noticed you are saying `this.gotoAndStop` which makes me believe you are in your button, so the function should be `this.ex.onRelease = function()`.